# Wireguard/iptables: ICMP response not forwarded to wg0

Tags: iptables, wireguard

Network diagram: `Laptop (10.8.0.2) -> (wireguard) -> server A (10.8.0.1, 10.10.0.10) -> server B (10.10.0.20)`

[sequence diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AY1CU.png)

I've connected my laptop (10.8.0.2) to a server A (10.8.0.1) via Wireguard.
I can ping/curl to the server A (10.10.0.10), but not another server B (10.10.0.20).

When `ping 10.10.0.20` server B from my laptop, I find the following on server A:

- `tcpdump -nn -i wg0` shows request, but no response:
- `tcpdump -nn -i enp7s0` shows request and response

So **the problem seems to be that the response is not forwarded from enp7s0 to wg0.**

But why not?

This is my iptables configuration:

```
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp7s0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp7s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Laptop wireguard:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 10.8.0.2/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.0/24,10.10.0.0/24
Endpoint = ...
```

Server A wireguard:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 
Address = 10.8.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
SaveConfig = true
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o cilium_host -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp7s0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o cilium_host -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp7s0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = 
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.2/32
```

Server B and server A are connected via a virtual private network.

**Update: wireguard service reload**

Restarting the service also seemed to help.

```
systemctl reload wg-quick@wg0.service
systemctl restart wg-quick@wg0.service
```

You can also try adding these rules, but I removed them and it still worked:

```
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
```

**Update: Other related problems (FYI):**

When I analyzed my routing table (`ip route`):

```
default via 172.31.1.1 dev eth0 
10.0.0.0/24 via 10.0.1.50 dev cilium_host proto kernel src 10.0.1.50 mtu 1400 
10.0.0.0/8 via 10.0.0.1 dev enp7s0 
10.0.0.1 dev enp7s0 scope link 
10.0.1.0/24 via 10.0.1.50 dev cilium_host proto kernel src 10.0.1.50 
10.0.1.50 dev cilium_host proto kernel scope link 
10.0.2.0/24 via 10.0.1.50 dev cilium_host proto kernel src 10.0.1.50 mtu 1400 
10.0.3.0/24 via 10.0.1.50 dev cilium_host proto kernel src 10.0.1.50 mtu 1400 
10.8.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
172.31.1.1 dev eth0 scope link
```

I realized that `10.0.0.0/8 via 10.0.0.1 dev enp7s0` was conflicting with the other routes, due to the 10.10.0.0/24 subnet belonging to a larger 10.0.0.0/8 range. So I moved my Kubernetes/Cilium network (to avoid 10.0.0.0/8 that could conflict with common networks at coffee shops etc.), and narrowed the VPC network as well.

Comment: You should post your wireguard confs on the three hosts. iptables is not responsible for where the traffics go.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the details. My estimate is that the problem is with iptables, not wireguard, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Well, if your `FORWARD` table is actually filtering, you will also need to allow replying traffics to be forwarded back out of `wg0` (either statefully or by matching with `-o wg0`). Server B also needs to have correct route for `10.8.0.2/32` (or `10.8.0.0/24`) unless `cilium_host` or `enp7s0` is really the vpn tunnel interface. Also make sure IP forwarding is enabled sysctl-wise.

Comment: Btw, although not really related to the issue here, it doesn't seem like you should have `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0` under the `[Peer]` section for `Laptop` (but `AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.2/32`). (Unless Laptop is supposed to be serving as an Internet gateway for other VPN clients.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `AllowedIPs` was incorrectly configured.

Comment: Yes, but I suspect your `FORWARD` table isn't actually filtering anyway (i.e., no fallback DROP/REJECT rule and chain policy is ACCEPT), so probably you don't need any `-A FORWARD` anyway. (`iptables-save` will give us the full picture)

Comment: That was the problem. AllowedIPs was set incorrectly. Do you want to create an answer so I can select it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: For the record, the keys you once pasted are still in the edit history. If you really want to be safe, use a new key pair.

Comment: @TomYan Thanks for your careful attention :). Btw, I found out that my VPC was using 10.10.0.0/24 subnet but in a 10.0.0.0/8 network, so my routing tables were conflicting with the Kubernetes/Cilium routing table (also 10.0.0.0/8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a second thought, the reason that it didn't work was probably `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0` causes the VPN-encapsulated traffics from Server A to B to be routed into the wireguard tunnel.

And the solution is hence replacing it with `AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.2/32`.